# Method called a GET instead of POST

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have this 'POST' method

```
[HttpPost]
[System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateProfile(string sAppUser)
{
    MobileProfileModel profileModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MobileProfileModel>(sAppUser);
    using (ucApp = new UserControllerApplication())
    {
        //this code should match the
        bool success = ucApp.UpdateUserProfile(profileModel);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.Created, success);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { result = success });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
}
```

and i calling it like this AJAX 'POST'

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://mydomain.com/api/User/UpdateProfile",
    data:JSON.stringify(profile),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    //dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
         $.blockUI({ message: "Success" });
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    },  
    beforeSend: function() {
       $.blockUI({ message: $("#ajaxLoader") });
    },
    complete: function() {
       $.unblockUI();
    }
});
```

and im getting this error

```
<Error>
<Message>
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
</Message>
</Error>
```

The problem is Im not calling a GET method and the method isnt marked as a GET either.  I am not sure what the issue is.

**UPDATE**
these are my route definitions

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //specific route for just the public views
    routes.MapRoute(
    "publicview",
    "publicview/details/{userName}",
    new { controller = "publicview", action = "details", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I am executing a Get method on the same controller and it works, this actually the post of that initial get.

Comment: Are you making an ajax call from the same domain to the same domain ?

Comment: Any solutions?
Is this on all browsers?
I get this in Chrome only....

Comment: is it only happening in chrome.  I dont remember if this particalur issue was solved its been so long

Answer (score 0):

i think there 2 are reasons for this error msessage:

1. your server uri routing routes your request to the wrong method
2. your ajax request are calling the wrong uri

if you want to be sure for calling POST look take a look via wireshark or try a different tool for post (e.g. curl)

**UPDATE**

your uri form AJAX reqeust is:

```
/api/User/UpdateProfile
```

your uri template is:

```
api/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

I think you get this error because they don't match.

by the way: you should not use post for updating a profile, use PUT with an ID

for example:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/api/User/UpdateProfile/"+UserID,
            data:JSON.stringify(profile),
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            //dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                 $.blockUI({ message: "Success" });
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            },  
               beforeSend: function() {
                   $.blockUI({ message: $("#ajaxLoader") });
               },
               complete: function() {
                   $.unblockUI();
               }
        });
```

and in the controller:

```
[HttpPut]
    [System.Web.Mvc.ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateProfile(string sAppUser) // I don't know how to parse the id from uri ;) 
    {
        //find the user by his uniqe ID
        MobileProfileModel profileModel= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MobileProfileModel>(sAppUser);
        using (ucApp = new UserControllerApplication())
        {
            //this code should match the
            bool success = ucApp.UpdateUserProfile(profileModel);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<bool>(HttpStatusCode.Created, success);

            string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { result = success });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Added my current route definitions that are working everywhere else in the system

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here, firstly is there any reason why you have used full path in your ajax request and not absolute path ? Is this only for example purpose ? I would recommend you to you absolute path.

Next if you could try this in your ajax call, change the following

```
url: "http://mydomain.com/api/User/UpdateProfile",
```

to

```
url: "/api/User/UpdateProfile/" + profile,
```

Or else if you want to use the `data:` attribute in your ajax call use like this

```
data: {sAppUser: profile},
```

Let me know if this doesnt help.

Comment: the reason for the full path is the call is being called from a entire different site